# How can I securely do passowordless(Important) windows authentication in an angular 7 web application

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jwt, angular7

How can I  securely do passowordless(Important) windows authentication  in the same domain in an angular 7 web application(Backend made with .net core 3.1)

Comment: does anyone have an idea?Just waiting for a way

Answer (score 0):

I found Microsoft's Library for Active Directory Authentication. Its Msal.Js

But this library is used for "azure" active directory.